# official web-site to download ldapjdk.jar and netscape.jar

Tags: java, ldap, sun

Can anyone please point me to the offical site where I can download ldapjdk.jar and netscape.jar.
I tried to search it on oracle but couldn't find it. I also guess it gets shipped with some package.

Comment: I don't think either of those have been developed in some time, consider the UnboundID LDAP SDK instead.

Comment: Please provide a listing of the objects in the netscape.jar and I may be able to locate it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The ldapjdk.jar is the same as ldapsdk and more than likely 4.1 based on experience and using the same files found on my system from some old software.

```
MD5 (ldapjdk.jar) = 8723807d24d5749fc2e39532a980cdda
MD5 (ldapsdk-4.1.jar) = 8723807d24d5749fc2e39532a980cdda
```

The Maven Central Repository contains the ldapsdk at the following coordinates:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>ldapsdk</groupId>
   <artifactId>ldapsdk</artifactId>
   <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The source code can be found on the Mozilla Archive server here: [Directory Server- Java SDK](https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/directory/java-sdk/)

The other library may be known as something else.